# Switching between series and parallel connection of batteries using relays

Tags: batteries, relay, switching

I attached a sketch about my project. There are two battery banks which are connect in series and parallel each. The fully charged bank consists of two 12 V batteries should always connected in series. That means that the parallel connection should be disconnected. The battery bank which is discharged should be in parallel (both 12 V batteries in parallel). That mean that the serial connection should be connected. The load (which is the same) should be connected always to the fully charged battery bank. I hope it is clear. :)
Which type of relays would you engage?

To detect the SOC of both banks I want to use an Arudino controller.
But the first question is how to solve this problem?

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: Get a 24V charger and the problem disappears

Comment: No. I don't want that! it has to stay that way.

Comment: Your rough schematic seems to show the batteries in bank 1 and bank 2 in both series and parallel connection. Perhaps you mean the blue wires are for series and the black wires for parallel? You will need to consider the current that will be drawn, to specify a switch or relay.

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: @ipving - Hi, FYI I have reversed (rolled-back) the deletion of the image and the mention of relays. Those details have already been used in answers, so it is now too late to change the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you need *interlocks* to assure you don't get a Big Bang Boom when series and parallel contactors (big relays) are closed at the same time.  Let me see if I can recall the diagrams.

Here's the relay/contactor contact diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPYdVq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You see there's a huge flaming problem.   If *either* SP1 or SP2 is closed at the same time SS is closed, you have a dead short across the battery.  This is not "greasy kid stuff".

So, we need some *interlocks* (auxiliary contacts) on the big relays/contactors to assure that it is open (at rest) before the opposing one can close.  So here's an interlock diagram that might fit - remember, I'm just some voice on the Internet here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0FV8V.png)</sup>

Note these are *normally closed* and open when the contactor energizes.

Of course, if one of those interlocks sticks, big bang boom...

I suppose SP1 and SS could be replaced by one "pole" of a DPDT switch, and SP2 replaced by the other pole. But I'm assuming you're dealing with pretty big DC power here, and you seem price sensitive - a DC-rated transfer switch rated for interrupting big power can be costly.  A rinky-dink little switch is a bad idea; arcing within the switch would be unstoppable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I see the problem. It's also possible that we start with a fully charged bank (two 12 volt in series) and no wires for parallel and a load on it and the other bank (two 12 volt in parallel) and no wires for series. Then the controller checks always which bank is empty and switch the jobs. Now the two batteries of the other bank which is fully charged, must be wired in series and not in parallel, then attach the load from the discharged bank to the full bank, disconnect the wires in series and wired them in parallel. Is that a better way?

Answer (score 1):

A DPDT relay and a fuse should suffice.

[image]

The fuse prevents the damage that could be caused by relay contact welding.

The probability of contact welding may be reduced by using a 'double-break' relay or contactor.

[image]

The output fuse is not shown.

**Final edit**

The schematic has been edited, further to your clarification that it's a 48 V inverter driven by four 12 V batteries.

It's to be noted that two relays and two 12 V chargers would be required.

However, it would be much simpler to charge the four batteries in series using a 48 V charger.

[image]

Comment: This looks very very good.

Comment: @ipving It does, except when the contacts get stuck together and the batteries are shorted out. There is no safety built-in, such as fuse or interlocking mechanism, so you need to add them.

Comment: Thank you, ipving.

Comment: @Justme - Hi, Thank you for your response. My answer has been edited.

Comment: @vu2nan Is there a DPDT relay which can handle 48 V and max. 60 amps?

Comment: Maybe using Mosfets, but how to hook to the batteries?

Comment: Hi ipving, What is the type of load?

Comment: A 48 V inverter

Comment: Hi ipving, Okay. You may have a look at the datasheet for DC contactor NL22E 48V DC. Here's the link - https://new.abb.com/products/1SBH143001R8322/nl22e-48v-dc. It's  rated operational current (DC-13) is 48V-134A. Utilization category DC-13 is for 'control of DC electromagnetics'. However, since in your application you are energising the contactor only for charging the batteries in parallel, I feel that it should be okay.

Comment: @vu2nan Thank you. What about latching relays such as these here:
https://www.ev-power.com.au/product/rel-ncr-80a/

Comment: Hi ipving,  Your 48 V inverter would require four 12 V batteries in series during operation and the same four 12 V batteries in parallel during charging. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Can you share your mail address? So I can send you better pictures and descriptions.

Comment: Hi ipving, Your requirement is now quite clear. The schematic has been duly edited. However, it would be much simpler to charge the four batteries in series using a 48 V charger.

Comment: @vu2nan: How about if I using 24 volt batteries instead of 12 volt batteries?
Which relays should I use? Latching relays? Thanks a lot. Happy new year!

Comment: Hi ipving, Inverter manufacturers use higher battery voltages at higher powers in order to limit battery current to about 40 A for ease of wiring and reduced cable cost.  For example, a single 12 V battery for a 500 W inverter and two 12 V batteries in series for a 1000 W one, the series batteries being charged at 24 V. In my opinion, the use of relays, to charge the batteries in parallel, unnecessarily complicates the design. Many thanks for the good wishes. Happy new year to you and your family too!

Comment: @vu2nan Hi, thank you. Do you know more about latching relays?
Can I switch DC with AC latching relays?

Comment: Hi ipving, Standard relay contacts are actuated when the coil is energised and released when the coil is de-energised.  Latching relay contacts may be actuated with a pulse input to a 'set' coil and released with a pulse input to a 'reset' coil.  Or the contacts may be actuated / released with alternate pulse inputs / reverse pulse inputs to the same coil. Standard electromagnetic and latch relays may have AC / DC coils switching AC / DC loads.